# How to raise events to page from Dynamically loaded user control?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have user control that inherits a base control class and these user controls are loaded using the LoadControl method, I can't seem to figure out how to raise events from user controls to the page that are dynamically loaded this way.

Thanks

Here is the delegate and event in the base user control class.

```
public delegate void SomeChangeEventHandler(object sender
, SomeChangeEventArgs e);

public event SomeChangeEventHandler SomeChangeEvent; 

public virtual void OnSomeChanged(SomeChangeEventArgs e)
{
    if (SomeChangeEvent != null)
    {
       SomeChangeEvent(this, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add event handlers manually like this:

```
MyUserControl myControl1 = (MyUserControl)LoadControl("ThisControl.ascx.cs");
myControl1.DataBinding += new System.EventHandler(this.MyControl_DataBinding);
```

Comment: I guess I don't understand what yor saying, I can add the event handler at the time I load the control?

Comment: I modified my answer to include an answer to your comment.

Comment: This is close but my event is in a control base class and the page can't see the method becuase the control is just a generic UserControl to the page therefore it can't see the custom event. Do I need to cast this to correct type first?

Comment: Yes.  I modified my answer (slightly) to show a type other than UserControl.

Comment: Thanks for your help that would work if I was trying to add an event for built in event of a control class or a usercontrol class, but how do I get my page to see the customevent with out casting to the correct type of usercontrol I just loaded?

Comment: This is what my modified answer shows.  You DO cast it to the type you are loading.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I am slow that means I should cast my user control to it's base type?

Comment: You should cast it to whatever object you need to, in order to access the event you need to handle.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad you got it working. Check out my new blog. I may be able to help in the future. http://www.thecodepage.com/